# Error - Bean Definition Overriding - ClientGemFirePropertiesConfigurer

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-gemfire

SSLConfiguration inherits ClientGemFirePropertiesConfigurer from EmbeddedServiceConfigurationSupport class. When I EnableSSL which loads SSLConfiguration, the runtime fails with error - Bean ClientGemfirePropertiesConfigurer already defined.

Library
spring-data-gemfire
2.2.0.RELEASE

Can you please advice how to resolve this?

I dont want to enable bean override at global level, we have other integrations that I don't want to impact for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

First, *Spring Data for VMware Tanzu GemFire* (SDG) `2.2` is already EOL. Ideally, you should use SDG `2.5` (i.e. `2.5.4`, the [current and latest](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-geode#learn) release).

Also, since SDG `2.4`, there are no longer any SDG bits based on GemFire since GemFire is no longer being released as a standalone product by VMware after GemFire `9.10`. SDG `2.3` was the last release with official bits for both Apache Geode and VMware Tanzu GemFire. SDG `2.3` was [based on](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode/blob/2.3.x/spring-data-geode/pom.xml#L23) Apache Geode `1.12` and ([based on](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode/blob/2.3.x/spring-data-gemfire/pom.xml#L22)) GemFire `9.10`, where GemFire `9.10` is based on Geode `1.12` (itself). Although [VMware Tanzu GemFire](https://tanzu.vmware.com/gemfire) is based on [Apache Geode](https://geode.apache.org/) in general, as of SDG `2.4`, SDG is [based on](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode/blob/2.4.x/spring-data-geode/pom.xml#L23) Geode `1.13` for which there are no GemFire releases, and so bits for GemFire were dropped.

Finally, SDG `2.3` is nearing EOL as Spring Boot has already stopped releasing and supporting Spring Boot `2.3` OSS, and commercial support is ending in 2022 (see [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Supported-Versions)).

Regarding your specific problem (involving bean definition overriding), I suspect you have conflicting and incorrect configuration in your application somewhere.

I wrote a [test](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode/blob/main/spring-data-geode/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/config/annotation/UsingAnnotationConfigWithBeanDefinitionOverridingDisabledIntegrationTests.java) demonstrating that SDG works correctly in this case.

This test [configures both Security (Auth) and SSL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode/blob/main/spring-data-geode/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/config/annotation/UsingAnnotationConfigWithBeanDefinitionOverridingDisabledIntegrationTests.java#L111-L112), since this is a common use case. Both Security (Auth) and SSL configuration involves configuring GemFire properties upfront (i.e. before GemFire starts) and therefore, both associated configuration classes (i.e. [SslConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode/blob/main/spring-data-geode/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/config/annotation/SslConfiguration.java#L45) and [GeodeIntegratedSecurityConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode/blob/main/spring-data-geode/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/config/annotation/GeodeIntegratedSecurityConfiguration.java#L35)) extend SDG's abstract `EmbeddedServiceConfigurationSupport` class.

Subsequently, this means both SDG Security and SSL enabling annotations will add `ClientGemFirePropertiesConfigurer` beans (1 for Auth/Security and 1 for SSL to the Spring `ApplicationContext`).

The result, SDG functions correctly and the [test](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode/blob/main/spring-data-geode/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/config/annotation/UsingAnnotationConfigWithBeanDefinitionOverridingDisabledIntegrationTests.java#L89-L107) **passes**, as expected. Additionally, the configuration is correct and this is the case even when the Spring container's `allowBeanDefinitionOverriding` property is **disabled**, as seen [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode/blob/main/spring-data-geode/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/config/annotation/UsingAnnotationConfigWithBeanDefinitionOverridingDisabledIntegrationTests.java#L67-L68), [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode/blob/main/spring-data-geode/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/config/annotation/UsingAnnotationConfigWithBeanDefinitionOverridingDisabledIntegrationTests.java#L121-L136) and then [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode/blob/main/spring-data-geode/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/config/annotation/UsingAnnotationConfigWithBeanDefinitionOverridingDisabledIntegrationTests.java#L78-L87).

> NOTE: The core Spring Framework allows bean definition overriding by default.  Only Spring Boot disables the core Spring container bean definition overriding by default.

Therefore, in my test, I explicitly disable bean definition overriding and verify that the Spring container bean definition overriding is, in fact, disabled.

Again, the test passes because all the `ClientGemFirePropertiesConfigurer` beans created by the SDG framework are in fact uniquely named, as you can see if you trace down to [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode/blob/main/spring-data-geode/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/config/annotation/support/EmbeddedServiceConfigurationSupport.java#L203-L205).

1 of the more common but less apparent ways in which this might be a problem is if you have duplicate (possibly conflicting) configuration, thereby making it non-obvious and ambiguous which configuration should take effect.

I can reproduce your error when I do just that, e.g. by specifying the `@EnableSsl` annotation on more than 1 Spring `@Configuration` class, that is [`IncorrectTestConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode/blob/main/spring-data-geode/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/config/annotation/UsingAnnotationConfigWithBeanDefinitionOverridingDisabledIntegrationTests.java#L115-L119) in addition to [`TestConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode/blob/main/spring-data-geode/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/config/annotation/UsingAnnotationConfigWithBeanDefinitionOverridingDisabledIntegrationTests.java#L109-L113). You can see this behavior if you [enable](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode/blob/main/spring-data-geode/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/config/annotation/UsingAnnotationConfigWithBeanDefinitionOverridingDisabledIntegrationTests.java#L66) the `incorrect-test-configuration` profile.

Of course, you should not specify SSL configuration more than once in your GemFire/Geode arrangement (and Spring [Boot] application).

Did you perhaps forget to distinguish which configurations should take effect by adding `@Profile` declarations, or maybe mistakenly enable more than 1 profile with conflicting configuration?

I only tested with SDG `2.5` bits (and above).  If this was a problem for `2.2`, then since SDG `2.2` is already EOL, I would suggest you upgrade as we will not be patching the SD[G] `2.2` release line any further.

If you are convinced this is still a bug in the latest release even, then please share a simple code sample that reproduces the problem and file an GitHub Issue ticket [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode/issues).

Comment: I may have thought of another scenario where this is still a problem... component based SSL configuration (e.g. client/server vs. WAN).  Therefore, a user might want to declare the `@EnableSsl` annotation multiple times to configure individual network components (e.g. again, client/server vs. WAN) of GemFire/Geode separately.  I will investigate further and get back to you when I know more.

Comment: After further investigation, even component-based SSL configuration uses the same general SSL settings (i.e. ciphers, keystore/truststore, protocols, etc).  However, the keystore/truststore can store certs per component and be referenced in GemFire/Geode properties using component certificate aliases.  This ultimately means you still only want to declare 1 SDG `@EnableSsl` annotation and **NOT** multiple per Geode component.  Instead you would store all certs in the same keystore/truststore and distinguish by component certificate aliases.  My answer above stands correctly.